# Можно ли как-то поставить блок с абсолютным позиционированием поверх другого такого же блока

Tags: html, css

У меня есть `header` с `position: absolute;` в котором есть какой-то контент, но следующий блок закрывает его (тоже с `position: absolute;`)
Но в `header` есть еще один блок который мне нужно поставить поверх всего
Пример:

```css
.header{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: yellow;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  top: 0;
}

.left{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
}

.section{
padding-top:20px;
  background-color: red;
  height:90px;
  width:100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 40px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="left">
    Header-content
  </div>
</header>
<div class="section">
   Some-content
</div>
```

Мне нужно только чтоб блок с классом `left` был поверх всего, красный блок был так же поверх желтого но контент который в желтом блоке должен ложиться поверх и красного и желтого, возможно ли это, заранее спасибо)

Comment: убрать у .header z-index: 1;

Comment: Серьезно, все было так просто, часа 4 голову ломал))
Можешь как ответ это написать чтоб я его отметил галочкой)